# Need Explaination of Clang AST Viewer form my Example

Tags: abstract-syntax-tree, clang++, llvm-clang, clang-ast-matchers

I tried to print the AST of the code below using **x86-64 clang 10.0.0 Ast Viewer**

```
int main() {return  'c';}
```

And I got this:

```
TranslationUnitDecl
`-FunctionDecl <line:1:1, col:25> col:5 main 'int ()'
  `-CompoundStmt <col:12, col:25>
    `-ReturnStmt <col:13, col:21>
      `-ImplicitCastExpr <col:21> 'int' <IntegralCast>
        `-CharacterLiteral <col:21> 'char' 99
```

Now, after this I tried to change return char 'c' to 'cw' and I got:

```
int main() {return  'cw';}
```

And I got this:

```
TranslationUnitDecl
`-FunctionDecl <line:1:1, col:26> col:5 main 'int ()'
  `-CompoundStmt <col:12, col:26>
    `-ReturnStmt <col:13, col:21>
      `-CharacterLiteral <col:21> 'int' 25463
```

now, why -ImplicitCastExpr is gone, even from ('char' 99) it's now become ('int' 25463). I need explanation, Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

According to cpp-reference (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/character_literal):

> narrow character literal or ordinary character literal, e.g. 'a' or '\n' or '\13'. Such literal has type char..

and regarding multicharacter literals:

> Multicharacter literal, e.g. 'AB', has type int and implementation-defined value.

Thus, for your first example, you have a narrow character literal 'c' which is implicitly cast to int because the return type of main is int. On the other hand, the multicharacter literal 'cw' is already treated as an int thus it does not require an implicit cast.

Note that this is for C++. In C, both (narrow and multi character literals) are of type int.